# Discord.js interaction.reply() took +- 2s to respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When I execute a command(/) the bot receives the command, processes the information and responds within milliseconds but Discord takes about 2 seconds to display the message. The other bots work fine and take ms to respond, but mine takes a while.

I have seen if it was for ratelimit but it is not for that and it is not stopped in an await or anything, I have a log just before the reply and it is sent within milliseconds, the same as the reply.

I have tried using other commands but is the same with every command. /ping responds with 110ms ping.

GitHub repo in case it helps :)
https://github.com/XurxoMF/ModeretaV14

EDIT: It is not when replying to an interaction, it is whenever you send or edit a message, messageCreate, interactionCreate... any type of reply() or send().

Comment: Try using `console.log()` and `console.time()` to log how long each step in your procedure. Find the step that is taking longer than expected and debug

Comment: Since the interactionCreate event arrives until the response is sent, 13,952ms, 10.55ms and 10.01ms elapse(I tried 3 times). But in the Discord channel took between 2 and 3 seconds ;-;

EDIT: The API ping is 100ms +-(at least is what the ping command says)